# Is closed linear functional a bounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Prove that a linear functional on normed linear space is closed if and only if it is continuous.

If it is continuous, it is pretty obvious that the operator is closed.Since for every convergent sequence, image is also convergent  sequence converging to image of limit of the sequence.

I'm not sure how to prove the other way.
Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: This is the closed graph theorem. Maybe look at a proof of the closed graph theorem.

Comment: For the closed graph theorem you need Banach spaces, but you aren't given completeness of the domain. Let $f$ be a closed linear functional. The point $(0,1)$ lies outside the graph of $f$ (since $f(0) = 0$), hence it has a neighbourhood that doesn't intersect the graph. How does a neighbourhood of a point in a product of two spaces look like? If you know that, you'll find a neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ such that $f(U)$ is bounded. You probably know that the existence of such a neighbourhood implies the continuity of $f$.

Comment: The point (0,0) has to be isolated point of the graph. Else, there must be exist a point (0,$ \epsilon $) for some $ \epsilon $ >0  in the graph which is not true. The norm used for (x,y) is sum of the norm of x and absolute value of y. I'm not sure how to obtain neighborhood U of 0 such that f(U) is bounded.